# Setting the last file status change time

Tags: macos, unix, filesystems

stat will report the last access time, last data modification time, and last file status change time.

utimes will allow one to set the last access time and last data modification time.

Is there a function that allows one to set the last file status change time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

st_ctime is updated whenever you change the file's names (move/rename/hardlink), ownership (chown/chgrp) or permissions (chmod/setfacl). There is no way to set this field to an arbitrary timestamp.

Comment: Well, there must be a way to set the timestamp because it changes - so some piece of code must be doing it somewhere. But, I agree, there doesn't appear to be any publicly accessible way to do it.